# JUNG change color of Nodes from green until white

Tags: java, graph, colors, graphics, jung

I'm trying to change the color of the Cluster Nodes from dark green to light green or white. But I don't have an approach for that, or I'm searching for an approach.

```
public WebSearchInterface() { setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    graph = GraphHandler.createForestTestempty();
    vv = VisualizationViewer.builder(graph)
                        .layoutAlgorithm(new StaticLayoutAlgorithm<>())
                        .layoutSize(layoutSize)
                        .viewSize(viewSize)
                        .graphMouse(graphMouse)
                        .build();

    vv.addPreRenderPaintable(
                new LayoutPaintable.LayoutBounds(
                        vv.getVisualizationModel(), vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer()));     
        
        
    Box controls = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    controls.add(
                GraphControlHelpers.getCenteredContainer(
                        "Layout Controls", GraphLayoutSelector.builder(vv).initialSelection(1).build()));
        //controls.add(GraphControlHelpers.getCenteredContainer("Search",GraphLayoutSelector.InputtextF),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        controls.add(GraphControlHelpers.getCenteredContainer("Zoom",GraphControlHelpers.getZoom(vv)));
        controls.add(GraphControlHelpers.getCenteredContainer("Node properties",GraphLayoutSelector.GraphPropList));

        add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel = new VisualizationScrollPane(vv);
        add(panel);
}
```

Is my Cluster

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSmol.png)

I know I can use the following function. I don't know how to degree or change the color from dark green until very light green or white. Maybe some one has an idea. I also created a List of this green color's. But I'm searching for an approach to change the colors from dark green until very light green or white.

```
public static Color[] clusterColor =  {new Color(0, 102, 0), new Color(0, 153, 0), new Color(0, 204, 0), new Color(0, 255, 51), new Color(102, 255, 102)};   

       vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintFunction(v->{ // set vertex color
 
          else if(v.equals(Center)&&(!Center.isEmpty()))
          {
            return Color.yellow;
          }
          else if((!v.equals(Center)) // first cluster  v is an string 
          {
              cnt_Vertex = cnt_Vertex +1;
              System.out.println(cnt_Vertex);
              System.out.println(v);
                  return clusterColor[2];
          }
          return Color.blue;
        });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "change the colors from dark green until very light green or white".  Do you mean that you want individual nodes to have a gradient paint function (in which case see https://github.com/jrtom/jung/search?q=gradientpaint for examples), or that you have a list of nodes whose colors should interpolate between your first and last colors, or something else?